Reference request: if $f$ is real analytic and $\{x:f(x)=0\}$ has a limit point, then $f=0$
I would like to know a reference for the following theorem.

Theorem: If $f$ is a real analytic function on an open set $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and if $\{x:f(x)=0\}$ has a limit point in $G$, then
$f(x)=0$ on $G$.


This theorem is mentioned in the book "A Graduate Course on Statistical Inference" written by Li and Babu (see page 43).
According to this book, the proof of that theorem can be found in the book "Real and Complex Analysis" written by Rudin. However, Rudin's book gives a proof of that theorem only for complex analytic functions.

Thank you for your attention!

Maybe I am talking nonsense but can't we a real analytic function as a complex analytic function using some tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$?

Does the proof in Rudin use the fact that $G\subset\mathbb C$? I don't have that book but if the theorem states that $G$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$ but doesn't actually use that fact in the proof, then the proof should carry over to your case.

this is not true unless $p=1$ - note that $xy$ is analytic but zero when $x=0$ or $y=0$; for $p=1$ the proof is standard with power series and induction

@Conrad What if ${x:f(x)=0}$ contains a non-empty open set? Is it still false for $p>1$?

then indeed it is true with easy proof7

@Conrad could please provide me a reference? I’m writing some notes and I want to cite that result!

just do the proof the same you would do it for a complex series - for example take the set of points $D$ for which that happens (the function is zero on a neighborhood of any point in $D$) and show it is open (obvious), nonempty (by hypothesis) and closed (this requires a little power series frectioning)

@Conrad The problem is that the notes I'm writing is about statistics. I don't want to prove that theorem in my notes otherwise I'll have to write a whole section about analytic functions!

I see - this is such a well known result that I have no idea where you would find a reference specifically for the real case - usually
